# Number of new messages received in a kafka topic per unit time

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to chart number of new messages received per unit time (minute or hour) in a given Kafka topic.

I have seen posts around finding the number of current messages in a topic. As a potential solution I could query this number at each time interval, however, this doesn't account for expired messages (due to retention time).

Is there a way to get the number of new messages received in a kafka topic per unit time?

Answer (score 1):

In JMX metrics you can find `kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=MessagesInPerSec` which indicates the incoming message rate. you can store it in Prometheus or another time series database and query it based on time.